# How to delete item from listView?

Tags: android, listview

I fetch data from SQLite in Listview .I need to delete this item when user click on check
box and press the delete button or only clicking on the check box,
I don't understand how to do this? Here is my sample code for reference.

MyTable.java

```
public class MyTable extends ListActivity {


 MySQLiteHelper m=new MySQLiteHelper(this);
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);       
    ArrayAdapter<Model> adapter = new InteractiveArrayAdapter(this,
            getModel());
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}


private List<Model> getModel()
{

    List<Model> list = new ArrayList<Model>();
    final MySQLiteHelper m=new MySQLiteHelper(getBaseContext());
    final List<LocWiseProfileBeans> LocWiseProfile= m.getAllLocWiseProfile();       

    for (final LocWiseProfileBeans cn : LocWiseProfile) {

    list.add((get(cn.getLocname())));
    //list.add(get(cn.getSelectedprofile()));

    // Initially select one of the items
    list.get(0).setSelected(true);

    }
    return list;
}
private Model get(String s) {
    return new Model(s);
}
```

InteractiveArrayAdapter.java

```
    public class InteractiveArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {

private final List<Model> list;
private final Activity context;

public InteractiveArrayAdapter(Activity context, List<Model> list) 
{
    super(context, R.layout.locprofile, list);
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    protected TextView text;
    protected CheckBox checkbox;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = null;

    if (convertView == null) {


        LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
        view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.locprofile, null);

        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        viewHolder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label);
        viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check);
        viewHolder.checkbox
                .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                            boolean isChecked) {
                        Model element = (Model) viewHolder.checkbox
                                .getTag();
                        element.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());

                    }
                });
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
        viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));

    } else {

        view = convertView;
        ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));

    }


    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    holder.text.setText(list.get(position).getName());
    holder.checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());


    return view;
}
}
```

MySQliteHelper.java

```
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "loc_wise_profile";
public static final String TABLE_NAME2 = "supervisor";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN1 = "loc_name";
public static final String COLUMN2 = "lattitude";
public static final String COLUMN3 = "longitude";
public static final String COLUMN4 = "selectedprofile";
public static final String COLUMN5 = "contactno";
public static final String COLUMN6 = "message";
//public static final String COLUMN7 = "enabled";
public static final String COLUMN8 = "NotificeationMessage";

SQLiteDatabase db;   
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "locale";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

// Database creation sql statement
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table IF NOT EXISTS "
        + TABLE_NAME + "( " + COLUMN_ID
        + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
        + COLUMN1 + " text not null, "
        + COLUMN2 + " double not null, "
        + COLUMN3 + " double not null, "
        + COLUMN4 + " text not null ,"
        + COLUMN5 + " text not null ,"
        + COLUMN6 + " text not null ,"
        //+ COLUMN7 + " text not null ,"
        + COLUMN8 + " text not null "
        + ");";



public MySQLiteHelper(Context context)
{
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    //database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE2);
}


  // Adding new Location wise Profile
public void insertLocWiseProfile(LocWiseProfileBeans loc) {
     db= this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN1, loc.getLocname()); // Contact Name
    values.put(COLUMN2, loc.getLattitude()); // Contact Phone Number
    values.put(COLUMN3, loc.getLongitude());
    values.put(COLUMN4, loc.getSelectedprofile());
    values.put(COLUMN5, loc.getContactno());
    values.put(COLUMN6, loc.getMessage());
    //values.put(COLUMN7, loc.getEnabled());
    values.put(COLUMN8, loc.getNotificationMessage());
    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}



    // Getting All Contacts
 public List<LocWiseProfileBeans> getAllLocWiseProfile() {
    List<LocWiseProfileBeans> LocWiseProfileList = new ArrayList<LocWiseProfileBeans>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            LocWiseProfileBeans loc= new LocWiseProfileBeans();
            //loc.set
            loc.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
            loc.setLocname(cursor.getString(1));
            loc.setLattitude(cursor.getDouble(2));
            loc.setLongitude(cursor.getDouble(3));
            loc.setSelectedprofile(cursor.getString(4));
            loc.setContactno(cursor.getString(5));
            loc.setMessage(cursor.getString(6));
           // loc.setEnabled(cursor.getString(7));
            // Adding contact to list
            LocWiseProfileList.add(loc);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return contact list
    return LocWiseProfileList;
}


@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.w(MySQLiteHelper.class.getName(), "Upgrading database from version "
            + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion
            + ", which will destroy all old data");
    database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(database);
}
public void delete(int value)
{
    try{            
        SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_ID+"="+value, null);

}
    catch(Exception e){}

}


public void deleteAll(){
    try{
    //db.execSQL("delete * from "+ TABLE_NAME);

        SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);

    }catch(Exception e){}
}   

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `getView` prototype from:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

to

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

Then add to your `viewHolder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener` listener:

```
Model element = (Model) viewHolder.checkbox.getTag();
element.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());
InteractiveArrayAdapter.this.remove(InteractiveArrayAdapter.this.getItem(position));
list.remove(position); //here consider whether you can afford changing list
// If you want to add code to remove the element from the database too
```

I have not tried it myself, but it seems that will work.

**EDIT**: Following you request I am adding the code to delete the entry from your database:

In your `MySQliteHelper` class add the following method:

```
public void deleteByName(String name) {          
   SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();
   db.delete(TABLE_NAME, COLUMN1 +"=?", new String [] { name });
   db.close();
}
```

Then change the code of the listener:

```
Model element = (Model) viewHolder.checkbox.getTag();
element.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());
InteractiveArrayAdapter.this.remove(InteractiveArrayAdapter.this.getItem(position));

MySQLiteHelper m = new MySQLiteHelper(InteractiveArrayAdapter.this.context);
m.deleteNyName(list.get(position).toString());
list.remove(position); //here consider whether you can afford changing list
```

Here I assume your names are unique. In case this is not true you will need to refactor your `Model` class (which, by the way, is already too confusing and I am just wild guessing that model.toString() will return the string of the name).

Comment: I need to delete it also from database.But how match position to database record _id? pls give me hintor code for delete from database. Thanks

Comment: and when i click on one item it delete all item?

Comment: About the second comment: you mean that is the result, or that is your expected behaviour? Btw I corrected a bit my code.

Comment: As for the first question: I can not help you there as long as you have not posted any code of your `MySQLiteHelper` class. However, I think you should try doing it yourself first. You get the item via `list.get(position)` and from then on you can use whatever is suitable for identifier and delete the record from the database with the appropriate method.

Answer (score 1):

`OnListItemClick`   just remove your list element like ...

```
list.remove(position)
```

and then just `refresh` your listview using `adpter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

and also remove from database from get value or using Position.